# Transient attributes removed in after_save callback in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I use a transient attribute during the [after_save](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_save) callback in Rails ActiveRecord class?

This is what I am doing right now.

I have a model class with multiple attributes that are backed by the DB. I want to add a transient attribute, say `a` which will not be stored in the DB.

```rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

 after_save :after_save_callback_func
 attr_accessor :a

 def after_save_callback_func
   puts self.a
 end

 def some_random_func
  self.a = 'Hello World'
 end
  
end
```

I wish to use the value set in the transient attribute `a` during the `after_save` callback but I see that the transient attribute is no longer present in the `self` object.

Comment: self[:a] = "Hello World" should work

Comment: What you already has works. Maybe you think it doesn't because `puts` isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: Hmm, actually, just noticed the superclass - which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: The pattern should work. But I see two potential problem with your specific example: 1) Do you actually set `a`? In your example, `a` will be `nil` and `puts nil` outputs an empty line. 2) Where do you expect to see the message? In a console? In a log file? I suggest using `Rails.logger.debug "value of a: #{a.inspect}"` or `puts "value of a: #{a.inspect}"` instead, by that you should see at least some output even if `a` is still `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, this pattern works as is. What was not working was this in the spec files for the unit tests.